# Java URL Connection blank input stream

Tags: java, url, urlconnection

The application I am working on has a terribly slow loading web page.  If I run the following code it works fine but only because of the call to `sleep`.  If I don't sleep then the InputStream is just a bunch of spaces, probably due to the application it is calling from.  Is there any non-hack way around this?

```
public class PublishTool extends Thread {

  private URL publishUrl;

  private String filerLocation;

  public PublishTool() {
  }

  public PublishTool(String publishUrl, String filerLocation) throws NibException {

    try {
      this.publishUrl = new URL(publishUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      throw new NibException("Publish Url :" + publishUrl + " is not valid. ");
    }

    this.filerLocation = filerLocation;

  }

  public void run() {

    File filerFile = new File(filerLocation);
    BufferedWriter writer = null;


    try {
      URLConnection conn = publishUrl.openConnection();
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream())));

      writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filerLocation));

      Thread.sleep(1000l);

      while (reader.ready()) {
        writer.write(reader.readLine() + "\n");
      }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Malformed URL for : " + publishUrl + " " + filerLocation, e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("IO Exception for  : " + publishUrl + " " + filerLocation, e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Thread was interrupted early... publishing might have failed.");
    } catch (NibException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Publishing File Copy failed : " + filerLocation + ".bak" + " to " + filerLocation);
    } finally {
      try {
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the value of "publishUrl"?

Comment: This code is all sorts of broken.

Comment: errors i've spotted: .close not in finally block(s); readline for binary data will break things, conn not closed at all, buffered reader/writer normally only need to be used in one direction. may post answer tomorrorw when i'm sober.

Comment: @Andreas: Also, url is never used, inputStream can't be set to an InputStreamReader, and reader isn't attached to any input stream.

Comment: Sorry.. I was doing this in a rush yesterday.. The system I am writing this for is all kinds of busted so I was trying to get rid of some off the confusing cruff.  Will try to clean it up a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use reader.ready(). Just call readLine() and let readLine() block until the data's ready. The end of the data will generally be signalled with a null line.

In case its helpful, a couple of code examples on my web site: [reading from a URL](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/networking.shtml).

Comment: So something like:

      while (!reader.readLine().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        writer.write(reader.readLine() + "\n");
      }

I just ran my test case and this seems to work.

Comment: Essentially, yes. The end of data will be signalled with null, though.

Comment: Cool man.. thanks for the link... I'd vote you up if I could!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it would be helpful if you posted your actual code.

My guess the problem is calling `Reader.ready`. Similar to `InputStream.available`, that returns `true` if there is already buffered input. If it needs to wait for, say, a socket the it will return `false`. Generally you don't need `ready`. Use `readLine`, and break out of the loop if it returns `null` (for end of stream).